# How to initialize the field of struct refrencing field of other struct in Go

Tags: go

I have two structs

```
type Service struct {
    

    Label string `json:"label" gorm:"type:varchar(50)"`
    Code  string `json:"code" gorm:"type:varchar(50)"`

    my.Active1
    
}
```

And in other package

```
package my
type Active1 struct {
    IsActive uint8 `json:"is_active" gorm:"type:tinyint(1) unsigned;not null;default:1;index"`
}
```

While instantiating struct ,I can easily do something like

```
s := entity.Service{
        Label:      payload.Label,
        Code:       payload.Code,
        my.Active1:  // how to initialize this field ??
    }
```

I am not getting any way to initialize the referenced field ,how to do so any idea ?

Answer (score -1):

Initializing a struct with another nested struct can be done using a struct literal like so:

```
s := entity.Service{
        Label:      payload.Label,
        Code:       payload.Code,
        my.Active1:  my.Active1{ 
            IsActive: uint8(1),
        },
    }
```

Here's an example in [Go Playground](https://go.dev/play/p/CvOXHicIhoV).